# Generate CSR from existing certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate

Can we generate the CSR (certificate signing request) used for certificate signing from the signed certificate? It should work with the original private key when signed again with different authority.

Answer (score 9):

Can't you just create a new CSR with your existing key?

```
openssl req -out CSR.csr -key your-existing-key.key -new
```

Comment: I do not have access to the current KEY and it is in the device, now I can just add the certificate.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible. The CSR has to be signed with the private key (see [RFC 2986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986)):

> The signature process consists of two steps:

> 1. The value of the certificationRequestInfo component is DER
>    encoded, yielding an octet string.
> 2. The result of step 1 is signed with the certification request
>    subject's private key under the specified signature
>    algorithm, yielding a bit string, the signature.

The signature serves as "*proof of possession*". Without it you could let CAs issue a certificate for somebody else's key.